# deprecated_mass_assignment_security.rb:14:in `attr_accessible' [voting gem][rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, when running

```
[leap_staging]$rails g reputation_system
```

After including the gem 'activerecord-reputation-system', require: 'reputation_system' in my Gemfile I get the below error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/deprecated_mass_assignment_security.rb:14:in `attr_accessible': `attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one. (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-reputation-system-2.0.2/lib/reputation_system/models/evaluation.rb:25:in `<class:Evaluation>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-reputation-system-2.0.2/lib/reputation_system/models/evaluation.rb:18:in `<module:ReputationSystem>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-reputation-system-2.0.2/lib/reputation_system/models/evaluation.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-reputation-system-2.0.2/lib/reputation_system.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/apane/Downloads/leap_staging/leap_staging/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

It's clear to me that this had to with Rails 4 and the new Strong Params. However, I'd like to get this workin'. So, how can I get this to work or convert it to strong_params if I can't even generate the files?

See the full app here if necessary for easy troubleshooting: www.github.com/apane/leap (gem not included)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the `protected_attributes` Gem into your Gemfile like the message says?

Comment: I'd rather not go that route if I don't have to. Unless there isn't a clear alternative :)

Comment: I seriously doubt there is - the parameter parsing has changed in Rails 4, you can either update your code, use the bridge gem or not upgrade :-P

Comment: the problem is, when I add the protected_attributes gem all of my controllers get messed up. I guess I have to resort back to the rails 3 syntax? e.g. no more strong_params.

Answer (score 0):

`activerecord-reputation-system` gem now supports Rails 4 (since version 3.0).